# I want to give some token to Anonymous User and store his data, if the user is registered back end should transfer the data

Tags: python, django, vue.js

here is the 'token'  generated on back end

```
    def get(self, request):
    if self.user.is_authenticated:
        # the logged user's data is stored

    else:
        token = get_random_string() #this function was imported from other file
```

here I am sending the token to requested url as Json file
but can't take it on front end  and send it to back end when the user is requested to the url
before the user already requested!
please help me out!!!
here is the Vue file in front end

```
searchProduct(keyword){
 if(this.selectedCatId != '' && this.selectedCatId != 'all'){
   this.$router.push({name: 'search', query:{
     k:keyword,
     cpn: this.$route.query.cpn ? this.$route.query.cpn : 1,
     cid: this.selectedCatId}
    })
 }else{
   this.$router.push({name: 'search', query:{
     k: keyword,
     cpn: this.$route.query.cpn ? this.$route.query.cpn : 1}
    })
 }
 this.$axios.get('requested url'+this.searchKeyword+'&pagenum=1&productsPerPage=10', {
    params: {
      usertoken: localStorage.getItem('unregUserSearchToken')
    }
 })
  .then(function (response) {
    localStorage.setItem('unregUserSearchToken', response.data.search_token)
    console.log(response);
  })
```

Comment: I tried , but could not reach to destination, when user search products requesting to back end is taking place two times at once, the result is saving data to the same user and generating new token creating second object

Comment: You should put the push route action in the request success callback

Comment: @sugars What do you mean? Can you show me what you wanted to say in the answer field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
searchProduct(keyword) {
  this.$axios.get('requested url' + this.searchKeyword + '&pagenum=1&productsPerPage=10', {
    params: {
      usertoken: localStorage.getItem('unregUserSearchToken')
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    localStorage.setItem('unregUserSearchToken', response.data.search_token)
    console.log(response);
    
    if (this.selectedCatId !== '' && this.selectedCatId !== 'all') {
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'search',
        query: {
          k: keyword,
          cpn: this.$route.query.cpn ? this.$route.query.cpn : 1,
          cid: this.selectedCatId
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'search',
        query: {
          k: keyword,
          cpn: this.$route.query.cpn ? this.$route.query.cpn : 1
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

You need to wait for the http request response before proceeding with the route jump operation, so as to ensure that the storage cache is correctly retrieved in the new page.